# Text below collapsible dropdown menu is unselectable, and links unclickable

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/8Mde7/1/) showing you [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/8Mde7/1/embedded/result/) of the dropdown menu I've written.

**The problem:**

[image: screenshot]

Part of the text (the site title link in this case) that is below the dropdown menu ("Channels") is unselectable / unclickable, while the other part below the normal "Home" link is rendered just fine. (You can try that in the demo.)

**Why I think this is happening:** I use JavaScript to dynamically change the `height` between `0` and `auto` values when the menu ("Channels") is clicked; NOT something like `display: none;`, and hence the menu-item element is only hidden, rendering the text that falls beneath it un-selectable/clickable.

[image: screenshot]

**The question is**, how do I fix this, without breaking the menu's current functionality and style (i.e. `transition` for dropdown). Everything I've tried, including `display: none | block;`, `visibility: hidden | visible;`, and `opacity: 0 | 1;` have failed me.

**EDIT:** As seen in the latest versions of Google Chrome and Chromium web browsers.

Comment: Your examples work fine withough the problem you describe in FF v17. what browser exhibits this problem ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Google Chrome & Chromium, latest versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work in FF

For Chrome where for some reason the child element (*of `#channels-menu-item-wrapper`*) does not respect the `overflow:hidden` of the parent use (*it respects the hidden in a visual manner only..*)

You can use a delayed transition and move the sub-element out of the way ..

```
.collapse > div{
    position:relative;

}
.collapse:not(.in) > div {
    left:-10000px;    
    -webkit-transition:left 0s ease;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.35s; /*same delay as the time it takes to open/close so it does not show*/
}
```

(*i have only added the `-webkit-` vendor specific rule.. apply for all*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cfH33/5/

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said at the end of my question, I've tried it. It breaks the menu's CSS animations (transition).

Comment: Just wondering, do you think this will NOT cause any unexpected issues? Is this a usual way of fixing these kind of problems?

Comment: Νot usual in the sense that this seems like a webkit bug. You original code should work just fine (*as it does in FF Opera and even IE(without transitions for ie)*)

Comment: @its_me, does the `width:0` of Praveen Vijayan work ? for me it does not transition the closing of the submenu..

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Weird. I think it worked when I checked the demo last night.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Set .collapse div's height and width to 0 <s>using script</s> when clicking on the menu.

**Update:** Form the @Gaby answer got this hint ".collapse:not(.in)".

```
.collapse:not(.in){
    width:0;
 }
```

This also will work. http://jsfiddle.net/8Mde7/3/

This is what I meant by setting width:0.

Comment: You have linked to my own fiddle.. just setting width 0 will instantly hide the submenu and so no transition will be shown..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - Opps. Sorry. I missed between tabs. link updated.

Comment: But that does not transition the closing of the submenu .. does it ? When you click to close it goes away directly..